# Using a proxy in a store in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My goal with this project is to load Json that's outputted by a script on a web server so that I can display data in a List in Sencha Touch 2.

I've looked at countless examples including answers from other people's questions on this website and I still can't seem to figure out what the problem is with my code. I'm sure it's something very small or perhaps some rule that I'm unaware of, but I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's my Model:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.model.Location', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['name','location','open','details']
    }
});
```

Here's my Store:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.Locations',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:[
        'Sencha.model.Location',
    ],
    config: {
        model: 'Sencha.model.Location',
        storeId: 'Locations',
        proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url : 'http://url/to/locations.php?filetype=.json',
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
      },
      autoLoad: 'true'
    }
    }
});
```

Here's the view where I want it to show up:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.LocationList',{
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    alias: 'widget.LocationList',
    xtype: 'locationlist',
    config: {
        title: 'What\'s Open @CU',
        disableSelection: true,
        itemTpl: '<img src="http://localhost/{open}.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:8px;" />{name}<span style="font-size:9pt;margin-left:8px;color:#888;">{location}</span>',
        store: 'Locations',
        onItemDisclosure: true
    }
});
```

Here's the JSON that's outputted(maybe it's a formatting problem that causes it to fail silently?)

```
{
"businesses":
    {
    "name" : "Baker's"
    "location" : "4th Floor Uni Centre"
    "open" : "open"
    "details" : "This is some information."
    }
}
```

Comment: Is "http://url/to/locations.php" in the same domain? No CORS issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON is not valid. You forgot the commas :

```
{
"businesses":
    {
    "name" : "Baker's",
    "location" : "4th Foor Uni Centre",
    "open" : "open",
    "details" : "This is some information."
    }
}
```

Also, if you intend to send more than one business, you might want to change the JSON format to something like this :

```
{
"businesses":[
    {
    "name" : "Baker's",
    "location" : "4th Foor Uni Centre",
    "open" : "open",
    "details" : "This is some information."
    },
    {
    "name" : "Baker's",
    "location" : "4th Foor Uni Centre",
    "open" : "open",
    "details" : "This is some information."
    }
    ...
]
}
```

and then add the `rootProperty: 'businesses'` to you're proxy's reader like nuthan said.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, the commas were definitely part of the problem! I also ended up changing how the JSON was generated and using JsonP, like suggested in one of the answers above. Seems silly to me that it would fail silently without telling you it found a problem with the Json, the rest of their error catching is so good! Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Add  `rootProperty:'businesses'` in the `reader: {
        type: 'json',
rootProperty:'businesses'
      }` of your Store.

Comment: Then businesses would have to be an array of JSON objects

Comment: I had that initially, but it didn't make a difference. Problem solved, it was a whole host of problems pointed out by the answerers below. Thanks anyways guys

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
http://url/to/locations.php
```

the same Location as your sencha touch app?
If not, than JsonP Proxy is needed. JsonP wraps Json data into function like context to make useable.

Comment: I ended up using JsonP. I got it to the point where it DID work using ajax, but for release I was planning on having the json outputted on a different server, so I was forced to learn how to use JsonP. Thanks :)